# Not able to publish content in dynamic module after sitefinity upgrade to 12.2

Tags: content-management-system, upgrade, sitefinity, sitefinity-8

Sitefinity site was upgraded from 8.2 to 12.2. But while trying to edit or create new content, the system is not responding. When checking the content goes to draft mode. Need some help with this. Users are not able to add any content because of this issue.

[image]

I am stuck with this. Please need some help to resolve this. Sitefinity support mentioned to disable the workflows and try, but that also did not work. Tried upgrading many times.

Comment: could be many things, have you checked for errors in the logs?

Comment: in my local machine, it is working fine. I am able to publish even though if it takes a minute or so

Comment: In error log file i found only the following message
Message: HandlingInstanceID: 559ba236-ba6d-4e6b-afdf-17404f3509d0
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred and was caught.
----------------------------------------------------------------
10/22/2020 16:55:04
Type : System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : The operation was canceled.
Source : 
Help link : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : 
HResult : -2146233088
Stack Trace : The stack trace is unavailable.

Comment: has the user got enough permissions to publish? I guess you have already tried a restart of the site? maybe worth trying deactivating and then activating the module

Comment: yes, the same user can publish like from the listing view of the dynamic module. Like selecting the check box and click publish. It publishes the content but UI is not updated. When the user refreshes the page then the status is showing published. Yes, I tried deactivating and activating the module and also restart.

Comment: What do you mean by this: "It publishes the content but UI is not updated" - do you mean the content is saved and published in the backend, but the frontend does not show the updated content?

Comment: I have added an image here. Publish is working from here while I click Publish but only after refreshing the manually it will reflect the change in status

Comment: That's weird. if you open the dev toolbar and explore the requests - does any of them fail, or maybe takes a long time to complete?

Comment: Nothing seems to fail when inspected. Seems like publishing is taking long time. Not sure why it is taking this much time.

Comment: Could see some workflow is created for the existing modules before upgrade. Disabling the workflow also did not help. Dynamic module created after upgrade is working fine and I am able to publish the content

Comment: could there be some custom code that listens on DynamicContentUpdate (Updating) events and trying to do something that fails?

Comment: haad some life cycle decorator class but tried debugging .. it did not get hit